# Magento 2.4.4 (PHP 8.1) Error while running setup:di:compile

Tags: setup-di-compile, magento2.4.4

**Compilation was started.**

```
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 77.0 MiBClass "Rsg\Enquiry\Controller\Index\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" not found#0 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/home/livinghab...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Rsg\\Enquiry\\Con...')
#3 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists('Rsg\\Enquiry\\Con...')
#4 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass('Rsg\\Enquiry\\Con...', '/home/livinghab...')
#5 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract(Object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
#6 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList('/home/livinghab...')
#7 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#8 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process(Object(Closure), Object(Closure))
#9 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /home/livinghabitat/public_html/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

I am getting this error when compiling my code. kindly help if someone can.

A big thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have incorrect using of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` (in current namespace instead of global) in `\Rsg\Enquiry\Controller\Index`

I suggest to review `\Rsg\Enquiry\Controller\Index` and check how and when `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` used and fix namespace issue

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for this:

- Check the composer version
- FPM is installed
- Having Custom Template issue

Most Probably its the reason of the composer version.

Thanks!